# How do I improve the physics on this rigid body cardboard box animation?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have a box.  I want to make it behave like it is made out of thick cardboard.

I have an object that I want to rise out of the box, and for the physics to look realistic.  This is how it looks now:

[image: box]

This is my "physics model" which I plan to connect to my rigged and properly designed box later on.

When I lift a sphere from inside the box, the flaps leap up, then slowly fall back as though they're made out of cast iron floating underwater.  How do I get them to behave like cardboard?

Blend file here:
https://file.io/2FHkpH3nIuot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, if you want it to behave like real cardboard, a *Rigid Body* simulation cannot achieve this - because cardboard is not completely rigid. If you would push the flaps up, they would slightly bend before they get pushed outside. The rigid body objects behave completely unflexible like steel plates (I know, in reality even they bend on a microscopic level). To simulate that cardboard more physically accurate, you should use *Soft Body* physics with very high stiffness settings. (Even then, real cardboard usually has an inner structure which makes the stiffness also dependent on the material's direction.)

**However**, a *Soft Body* simulation would be total overkill for this if you don't want to go hyper-realistic. I don't even think it acts very wrong. What makes those outer flaps shoot up like crazy is that they are very light, are fully rigid and most importantly, the inner flaps push them directly (or at least very close) at the hinges when coming up, so that in just one or two frames they are pushed a quite large angle upwards.

When you open a cardboard box from the outside, this usually doesn't happen because you first open the outer flaps. But when you actually open just one side, then grab an inner flap and pull it up, the second outer flap will be pushed up quite fast as well.

The difference to your simulation is, the cardboard material itself is damping the movement much stronger than your simulation does. The "hinge", which in real life is only a fold in the material, resists this motion much more and damps the swinging around.

**To make a long story short:** to improve your simulation, I would suggest you increase the rotation damping on those flaps (all four would be best). I saw in your file, you already increased the values under *Dynamics* > *Damping Translation*. But the damping for *Rotation* is quite low with the default 0.100, I would try at least 0.6 or more and check the result.